# int Method in C++ Class "Requies and Identifier"

Tags: c++, class, methods, declaration

I am attempting to make a class to contain some math operations from a CRC math tables handbook I have, in creating one of the functions I got a strange error I had not seem before. The code for both the cpp and the header are below:

```
//Header File
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#define int "CRCMathLib_H"

using namespace std;

class CRCMathLib
{
public:
    int DoReturn_Totient(int Toter); //Error comes from here when trying to declare as an int
};

//CPP Class File
#include "CRCMathLib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int CRCMathLib::DoReturn_Totient(int Toter)
{

    return 0;
}

//CPP Main File
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include "CRCMathLib.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The Main file does not do anything as of yet as this is a completely new file for these operations, I believe this may be a preprocessing error and its not picking up on the int statement as I ran it on another PC with VS and it was able to read the statement. anything would help. Also it was requesting a decleration of the header file, so thats why I placed the int there, is this possibly the issue? removing it returns the error of not having a decleration.

Comment: What is this declaration? `#define int "CRCMathLib_H"`

Comment: Strange guess. Since `return 0.0;` is actually attempting to return a *floating-point* value, what happens if you change to `return 0;` or `return Toter + 2;`? Other than the unused parameter `int Toter`, there really isn't anything that jumps out (of course the code really doesn't do anything either)

Comment: I went back to edit it, bc it was changed to a double and I forgot to change the return value, it should be return 0, sorry about that

Comment: as for that decleration in the define method, I added it bc VS was complainging that it didnt have a decleration, after adding the decleration, which I have no idea why this is needed (probably isnt), the program passed it off as normal

Comment: please include the error verbatim in the question

Comment: @ColorBand12 It's not a good idea to follow your compilers advice unless you understand what you are doing. Compiler error messages are notoriously misleading.

Comment: @ColorBand12 So after removing `#define int "CRCMathLib_H"` is the problem fixed, or do you have a different problem now?

Comment: Well, `"CRCMathLib_H" DoReturn_Totient("CRCMathLib_H" Toter);` is definitely not a valid function prototype. I suspect that you meant `#include` but wrote `#define` by accident, because you got it right in the other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .h remove `#define int "CRCMathLib_H"` which is most probably a typo
replace it by

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#pragma once
```

The `#pragma once` ensure you can safely include your .h from the cpp implementation file and the main.cpp

You mis understood include guard protection usually done by

```
ifndef CRCMathLib_H
#define CRCMathLib_H
// all of you .h file delcaration
#endif
```

This can be easily replace by the `#pragma once` statement at the begining of the file

More on this here: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-guards/

Comment: Thank you very much, I removed the ifndef from my header file in another CRCMathLib file and it worked fine so I presumed it wasnt required. works great now.